# jQuery slideToggle toggling elements separately

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I've styled the new WP Admin Bar to my liking, and added a "Hide" button. I set the button to slideToggle the "wpadminbar" div. When I click to hide it, the div and search form (which is nested in the "wpadminbar" div) **both** toggle. Here's a video of the issue...

[jQuery toggle problem](http://vimeo.com/20324430)

The code is pretty straight forward.

```
$(function()    {
    $("a#hide-admin").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('hidden', 1000);
        $("#wpadminbar").slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

The same thing happens when I change `.slideToggle` to `.toggle`. Any idea what's causing this and/or how to remedy it?

**EDIT**
Here's all of the pertinent code.

```
  <div id="wpadminbar">
    <div class="quicklinks">
      <ul>
                <li> Admin Bar links go here... </li>
    </div>
    <div id="adminbarsearch-wrap">
      <form action="http://myurl.com"
            method="get"
            id="adminbarsearch"
            name="adminbarsearch">
        <input class="adminbar-input"
              name="s"
              id="adminbar-search"
              type="text"
              value=""
              maxlength="150" /> <input type="submit"
              class="adminbar-button"
              value="Search" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#wpadminbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 41px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(images/adminbar-bg.png) repeat-x;
}

.quicklinks ul  {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  display: inline;
}

.quicklinks ul li   {
    display: inline;
}

.quicklinks ul li a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 41px;
    font-family: "Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #111;
}

#adminbarsearch {
    width: 250px;
    height: 41px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

#hide-admin {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    top: 51px;
    font: bold 11px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #C91D07;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#hide-admin.hidden  {
    top: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing the animated `toggleClass` **and** the `slideToggle`? Surely just the `slideToggle` would be enough?

Comment: can you provide some more code?

Comment: lonsomeday - toggleClass is for the button. Sorry I wasn't more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has to do with the `position:fixed` here

```
#adminbarsearch {
width: 250px;
height: 41px;
position: fixed;
right: 10px;
top: 10px;
}
```

if you remove that you will see that toggle now works fine

example http://jsfiddle.net/circadian/YvnrS/2/

Answer (score 2):

If your admin bar's CSS is already positioned in any way other than static (which it appears it may be), why not just animate the top position?

```
$('a#hide-admin').click(function () {
    $('#wpadminbar').add(this).animate({
        top: '-=' + $('#wpadminbar').height()
    }, 1000, function () {
        // Callback to manipulate the #hide-admin button if desired
    });
});
```

You'd just have to do only a tiny bit more thinking in the event you wanted a toggle back/forth kind of functionality. For example you could programmatically create the animation options object based on whether or not the bar was still on-screen, correctly modifying the {}.top value.

Comment: [A fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/p79AX/) to demonstrate the concept. :]